# fatal: unknown index entry format 0xa7e80000

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am getting Fatal error when i am running `git status` or `git pull`

> fatal: unknown index entry format 0xa7e80000

I also tried following commands, but it is not solved.

```
 rm -f .git/index
 git reset
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this issue was because of there were no **'Write'** permissions.
After setting Write permissions, issue was fixed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

1. Delete corrupted .git from your local repo.

> rm -rf .git

2. Initialize git repo again in your local project folder. This will make your local folder as local repo.

> git init

3. Add remote repo origin in your local project folder. This will sync your local repo with cloud git repo. This is done. You can interact with git cloud if your user is already added.

> git remote add origin remote_url

**Solution 2:**
(Courtesy to https://qiita.com/mkzyk/items/b7886a13045cacf2cbaf)

1. Create a backup of the corrupt directory (suppose local repo name is 'foo')

> cp -R foo foo-backup

2. Make a new clone of the remote repository to a new directory.

> git clone git@www.mydomain.de:foo foo-newclone

3. Delete the corrupt .git subdirectory.

> rm -rf foo/.git

4. Move the newly cloned .git subdirectory into foo

> mv foo-newclone/.git foo

5. Delete the rest of the temporary new clone

> rm -rf foo-newclone